# How to count the number of files not of certain types

Tags: powershell, directory-traversal

The code below counts the number of files of certain types in a directory and subdirectories:

```
$filetype = @("*.jpg", "*.jpeg","*.png","*.gif", "*.bmp")
$file_count = Get-ChildItem -Path $filepath -Include $filetype -Recurse -File | Measure-Object | %{$_.Count}
$output = "images: `t" + $file_count
Write-Output $output;
```

How would I count the number of all files that are not of these types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `-Include $filetype` with `-Exclude $filetype`